# how can I conversion list to array at ironpython?

Tags: ironpython, numeric, mathnet-numerics, revitpythonshell

I want to conversion list[int] to array[int] or int to array[int]

I tried to install Mathnet.numerics. but I don't know where I install it and how to install..

```
for i in range(len(lst)):   
   k = List.GetItemAtIndex(lst,i)
   p = array[
   o = List.RemoveItemAtIndex(lst,p)    
   l = Solid.ByUnion(o)
   Arr_u[i] = Geometry.IntersectAll(k,l)
```

it's my revit dynamo code(ironpython).
at `List.RemoveItemAtIndex(lst,p)`, p is must be `array[int]`.
but I can't change it.

> error code is "expected Array[int], got int"

Comment: List.RemoveItemAtIndex(lst,i) also has error

Comment: Hi Gunwoo, I havent had to use `Arrays` or `List.GetItemAtIndex` in RevitPythonShell before, and the question is very specific - perhaps an earlier question might be the easier question to answer? ie. 'How do I remove two items from a list and combine the result?'